# error deploying to heroku : no pg adapter, I DO have pg in productions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Error:
remote:        Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

bottom half of my gemfile:

```
group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'sqlite3'

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable? What are the contents of your `database.yml`?

Deploying to Heroku you usually don't need to specify an adapter, just the URL.
I.e.

```
default: &default
  url:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV["DB_POOL"] || ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5 %>

production:
  <<: *default
  sslmode: verify-full
  sslrootcert: config/ca/rds-ca-2015-root.pem
```

(Incidentally I think it's named `postgres`, not `postgresql`)

Comment: Im sorry im very new to ROR (Ruby on Rails) and dont' understand what your asking. This is supposed to be udemy course clone. Here's a link to my github link if that helps you to understand my error. https://github.com/Mnapper3/just2share.

Comment: Usually on Heroku, when you add a database add-on, it sets the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. Then, in `config/database.yml` you only need to reference it and Rails will pick up the adapter from the scheme of the URI.

Comment: Just like I described in the answer: make sure that there is a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable defined in your Heroku setup. Then you can use the provided snippet to setup `config/database.yml` and you should be good to go.